# jQuery to hide rows that do not have a certain class

Tags: jquery

I have the following psudeo html. I need to write some jquery which hides any rows which do not contain a table which has an anchor tag with a certain class 'FacetItemsActive'.

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td><a class='FacetItemsActive'/></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
normal content
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
normal content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have this function which is close, but not quite there. Can any of you jquery gurus help me?

```
function eiaHideNonSelectedFacets(){
    // find the parent facet table
    // find children tr of that table, and hide any rows that do not contain the class 'FacetItemsActive'
    $('.FacetItemsActive').closest('table[facet]').find('tr').each(function(){

        if (! $(this).is('.FacetItemsActive')){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nested tables are almost always a sign that you are using tables for layout, which [you should avoid](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html).

Comment: yea, I didn't create the html, I just have to work with it. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("tr:not(:has('.FacetItemsActive'))").hide();`

[Test](http://jsfiddle.net/Cxp6A/)

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you close an "a" tag.
Should use .

Comment: Forward slash, not backslash.